# In ruby what's the difference between object.class == and object.is_a?

Tags: ruby, class

In my app I do a check: `object.class == Array`. I came across a posting here regarding the difference between `.is_a?` and `.kind_of?` and `.instance_of?`

Since I thought `.is_a?` reads better than `.class ==`, I changed it, only to discover the one was true but the other was not. Note: this is in the context of reading an XML feed. Is this because there's implicit conversion of XML into arrays?

Comment: `is_a?` will match parent classes too.

Comment: I think this question could be clearly understood simply by reading the Docs. [`Object#is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) and [`Module#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D)

Comment: I understand with inheritance the .is_a? is true for subclasses too. But in this case, the "object.class == Array" was true, but the "object.is_a? Array" was false--which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Without the code it is impossible to tell why the code we can't see does something we can't reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one difference when it comes to inheritance. Here's one example:

```
class A;end
class B < A;end
b = B.new

b.is_a? A # => true
b.is_a? B # => true

b.class == A # => false
b.class == B # => true

b.instance_of? A # => false
b.instance_of? B # => true
```

Comment: I understand that since B subclasses A, b.class != A.However, in my case the object (an XML object).class == Array evaluates to true, but object.is_a? Array evaluates to false.